# In LightningChartJS remove the light on the spheres for PointSeries3D

Tags: lightningchart

Screenshot:
[image]

Is it possible to remove the light from the point spheres? The light doesn't appear on some colors like black, red, blue etc. However, with custom colors the light is there.

The idea being similar to PointSeriesTypes3D.Pixelated with the ability to set the shape to sphere.

For reference this is the code:

```
const series=this.chart.addPointSeries();
series.add(data); 

series.setPointStyle(
  new PointStyle3D.Triangulated({
    size: pointSize, 
    shape: 'sphere',
    fillStyle: new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX(color) }).setA(opacity) }) 
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be new APIs added in the next version release v3.1 (around end of July) that will allow configuration of light shading in 3D.

The effect you have described will be achievable then. With prior releases the light shading can't be altered unless 2D geometry is used, like Pixelated points.

I'll update this answer once the release is out.

EDIT:
With LCJS v.3.1, the effect you have described can be achieved by changing the "color shading style" of `PointSeries3D`.

```
series3D.setShadingStyle(new ColorShadingStyles.Simple())
```

https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.1.0/classes/pointseries3d.html#setcolorshadingstyle

Currently all 3D series support *simple* and *phong* color shading styles.